# Changing fullscreen gallery navigation to bullet-navigation

Tags: jquery, navigation, gallery

I'm a noob at modifying jQuery and have managed to do the odd simple piece of code, but its a bigger task for me to modify this gallery: http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/ - which currently uses a next/prev button and a digit counter e.g. 1/3, 2/3 etc...

I need to simply change the digit counter to bullet counters as found on sliders like http://wowslider.com/.

I tinkered with the jquery and tried a few things, but the changes could be much more than I anticipated. Any hints or tips to get me going?

Here is the actual JS:

```
(function($){

//Add in Supersized elements
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').prepend('<div id="supersized-loader"></div>').prepend('<div id="supersized"></div>');
});

//Resize image on ready or resize
$.supersized = function( options ) {

    //Default settings
    var settings = {

        //Functionality
        slideshow               :   1,      //Slideshow on/off
        autoplay                :   1,      //Slideshow starts playing automatically
        start_slide             :   1,      //Start slide (0 is random)
        slide_interval          :   5000,   //Length between transitions
        transition              :   1,      //0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
        transition_speed        :   750,    //Speed of transition
        new_window              :   1,      //Image links open in new window/tab
        pause_hover             :   0,      //Pause slideshow on hover
        keyboard_nav            :   1,      //Keyboard navigation on/off
        performance             :   1,      //0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
        image_protect           :   1,      //Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript
        image_path              :   'img/', //Default image path

        //Size & Position
        min_width               :   0,      //Min width allowed (in pixels)
        min_height              :   0,      //Min height allowed (in pixels)
        vertical_center         :   1,      //Vertically center background
        horizontal_center       :   1,      //Horizontally center background
        fit_portrait            :   0,      //Portrait images will not exceed browser height
        fit_landscape           :   0,      //Landscape images will not exceed browser width  

        //Components
        navigation              :   1,      //Slideshow controls on/off
        thumbnail_navigation    :   0,      //Thumbnail navigation
        slide_counter           :   1,      //Display slide numbers
        slide_captions          :   1       //Slide caption (Pull from "title" in slides array)

    };

    //Default elements
    var element = $('#supersized');     //Supersized container
    var pauseplay = '#pauseplay';       //Pause/Play

    //Combine options with default settings
    if (options) {
        var options = $.extend(settings, options);  //Pull from both defaults and supplied options
    }else{
        var options = $.extend(settings);           //Only pull from default settings       
    }

    //General slideshow variables
    var inAnimation = false;                    //Prevents animations from stacking
    var isPaused = false;                       //Tracks paused on/off
    var image_path = options.image_path;        //Default image path for navigation control buttons

    //Determine starting slide (random or defined)
    if (options.start_slide){
        var currentSlide = options.start_slide - 1; //Default to defined start slide
    }else{
        var currentSlide = Math.floor(Math.random()*options.slides.length); //Generate random slide number
    }

    //If links should open in new window
    var linkTarget = options.new_window ? ' target="_blank"' : '';

    //Set slideshow quality (Supported only in FF and IE, no Webkit)
    if (options.performance == 3){
        element.addClass('speed');      //Faster transitions
    } else if ((options.performance == 1) || (options.performance == 2)){
        element.addClass('quality');    //Higher image quality
    }


    /***Load initial set of images***/

    if (options.slides.length > 1){
        //Set previous image
        currentSlide - 1 < 0  ? loadPrev = options.slides.length - 1 : loadPrev = currentSlide - 1; //If slide is 1, load last slide as previous
        var imageLink = (options.slides[loadPrev].url) ? "href='" + options.slides[loadPrev].url + "'" : "";
        $("<img/>").attr("src", options.slides[loadPrev].image).appendTo(element).wrap('<a ' + imageLink + linkTarget + '></a>');
    }

    //Set current image
    imageLink = (options.slides[currentSlide].url) ? "href='" + options.slides[currentSlide].url + "'" : "";
    $("<img/>").attr("src", options.slides[currentSlide].image).appendTo(element).wrap('<a class="activeslide" ' + imageLink + linkTarget + '></a>');

    if (options.slides.length > 1){
        //Set next image
        currentSlide == options.slides.length - 1 ? loadNext = 0 : loadNext = currentSlide + 1; //If slide is last, load first slide as next
        imageLink = (options.slides[loadNext].url) ? "href='" + options.slides[loadNext].url + "'" : "";
        $("<img/>").attr("src", options.slides[loadNext].image).appendTo(element).wrap('<a ' + imageLink + linkTarget + '></a>');
    }
    /***End load initial images***/

    element.hide();                 //Hide image to be faded in
    $('#controls-wrapper').hide();  //Hide controls to be displayed

    $(window).load(function(){

        $('#supersized-loader').hide();     //Hide loading animation
        element.fadeIn('fast');             //Fade in background
        $('#controls-wrapper').show();      //Display controls

        //Display thumbnails
        if (options.thumbnail_navigation){

            //Load previous thumbnail
            currentSlide - 1 < 0  ? prevThumb = options.slides.length - 1 : prevThumb = currentSlide - 1;
            $('#prevthumb').show().html($("<img/>").attr("src", options.slides[prevThumb].image));

            //Load next thumbnail
            currentSlide == options.slides.length - 1 ? nextThumb = 0 : nextThumb = currentSlide + 1;
            $('#nextthumb').show().html($("<img/>").attr("src", options.slides[nextThumb].image));

        }

        resizenow();    //Resize background image

        if (options.slide_captions) $('#slidecaption').html(options.slides[currentSlide].title);        //Pull caption from array
        if (!(options.navigation)) $('#navigation').hide(); //Display navigation


        //Start slideshow if enabled
        if (options.slideshow && options.slides.length > 1){

            if (options.slide_counter){ //Initiate slide counter if active

                $('#slidecounter .slidenumber').html(currentSlide + 1);     //Pull initial slide number from options        
                $('#slidecounter .totalslides').html(options.slides.length);    //Pull total from length of array

            }

            slideshow_interval = setInterval(nextslide, options.slide_interval);    //Initiate slide interval

            //Prevent slideshow if autoplay disabled
            if (!(options.autoplay)){

                clearInterval(slideshow_interval);  //Stop slideshow
                isPaused = true;    //Mark as paused

                if ($(pauseplay).attr('src')) $(pauseplay).attr("src", image_path + "play_dull.png");   //If pause play button is image, swap src

            }

            //Thumbnail Navigation
            if (options.thumbnail_navigation){

                //Next thumbnail clicked
                $('#nextthumb').click(function() {

                    if(inAnimation) return false;       //Abort if currently animating

                    clearInterval(slideshow_interval);  //Stop slideshow
                    nextslide(element, options);        //Go to next slide
                    if(!(isPaused)) slideshow_interval = setInterval(nextslide, options.slide_interval);    //If not paused, resume slideshow

                    return false;

                });

                //Previous thumbnail clicked
                $('#prevthumb').click(function() {

                    if(inAnimation) return false;       //Abort if currently animating

                    clearInterval(slideshow_interval);  //Stop slideshow
                    prevslide(element, options);        //Go to previous slide
                    if(!(isPaused)) slideshow_interval = setInterval(nextslide, options.slide_interval);    //If not paused, resume slideshow

                    return false;

                });

            }

            //Navigation controls
            if (options.navigation){

                $('#navigation a').click(function(){  
                    $(this).blur();  
                    return false;  
                });

                //Next button clicked
                $('#nextslide').click(function() {

                    if(inAnimation) return false;       //Abort if currently animating

                    clearInterval(slideshow_interval);  //Stop slideshow
                    nextslide();        //Go to next slide
                    if(!(isPaused)) slideshow_interval = setInterval(nextslide, options.slide_interval);    //If not paused, resume slideshow

                    return false;

                });

                //If next slide button is image
                if ($('#nextslide').attr('src')){

                    $('#nextslide').mousedown(function() {
                        $(this).attr("src", image_path + "arrow_right_active.png");
                    });
                    $('#nextslide').mouseup(function() {
                        $(this).attr("src", image_path + "arrow_right_inactive.png");
                    });
                    $('#nextslide').mouseout(function() {
                        $(this).attr("src", image_path + "arrow_right_inactive.png");
                    });

                }

                //Previous button clicked
                $('#prevslide').click(function() {

                    if(inAnimation) return false;       //Abort if currently animating

                    clearInterval(slideshow_interval);  //Stop slideshow
                    prevslide();        //Go to previous slide
                    if(!(isPaused)) slideshow_interval = setInterval(nextslide, options.slide_interval);    //If not paused, resume slideshow

                    return false;

                });

                //If previous slide button is image
                if ($('#prevslide').attr('src')){

                    $('#prevslide').mousedown(function() {
                        $(this).attr("src", image_path + "arrow_left_active.png");
                    });
                    $('#prevslide').mouseup(function() {
                        $(this).attr("src", image_path + "arrow_left_inactive.png");
                    });
                    $('#prevslide').mouseout(function() {
                        $(this).attr("src", image_path + "arrow_left_inactive.png");
                    });

                }

                //Pause/play element clicked
                $(pauseplay).click(function() {

                    if(inAnimation) return false;       //Abort if currently animating

                    if (isPaused){

                        if ($(pauseplay).attr('src')) $(pauseplay).attr("src", image_path + "pause_dull.png");  //If image, swap to pause

                        //Resume slideshow
                        isPaused = false;
                        slideshow_interval = setInterval(nextslide, options.slide_interval);

                    }else{

                        if ($(pauseplay).attr('src')) $(pauseplay).attr("src", image_path + "play_dull.png");   //If image, swap to play

                        //Stop slideshow
                        clearInterval(slideshow_interval);  
                        isPaused = true;

                    }

                    return false;

                });

            }   //End navigation controls

        }   //End slideshow options

    });     //End window load

    //Keyboard Navigation
    if (options.keyboard_nav){

        $(document.documentElement).keydown(function (event) {

            if ((event.keyCode == 37) || (event.keyCode == 40)) { //Left Arrow or Down Arrow

                if ($('#prevslide').attr('src')) $('#prevslide').attr("src", image_path + "arrow_left_active.png");     //If image, change back button to active

            } else if ((event.keyCode == 39) || (event.keyCode == 38)) { //Right Arrow or Up Arrow

                if ($('#nextslide').attr('src')) $('#nextslide').attr("src", image_path + "arrow_right_active.png");    //If image, change next button to active

            }

        });

        $(document.documentElement).keyup(function (event) {

            clearInterval(slideshow_interval);  //Stop slideshow, prevent buildup

            if ((event.keyCode == 37) || (event.keyCode == 40)) { //Left Arrow or Down Arrow

                if ($('#prevslide').attr('src')) $('#prevslide').attr("src", image_path + "arrow_left_inactive.png");   //If image, change back button to normal

                if(inAnimation) return false;       //Abort if currently animating

                clearInterval(slideshow_interval);  //Stop slideshow
                prevslide();        //Go to previous slide

                if(!(isPaused)) slideshow_interval = setInterval(nextslide, options.slide_interval);    //If not paused, resume slideshow

                return false;

            } else if ((event.keyCode == 39) || (event.keyCode == 38)) { //Right Arrow or Up Arrow

                if ($('#nextslide').attr('src')) $('#nextslide').attr("src", image_path + "arrow_right_inactive.png");  //If image, change next button to normal

                if(inAnimation) return false;       //Abort if currently animating

                clearInterval(slideshow_interval);  //Stop slideshow
                nextslide();        //Go to next slide

                if(!(isPaused)) slideshow_interval = setInterval(nextslide, options.slide_interval);    //If not paused, resume slideshow

                return false;

            } else if (event.keyCode == 32) { //Spacebar

                if(inAnimation) return false;       //Abort if currently animating

                if (isPaused){

                    if ($(pauseplay).attr('src')) $(pauseplay).attr("src", image_path + "pause_dull.png");  //If image, swap to pause

                    //Resume slideshow
                    isPaused = false;
                    slideshow_interval = setInterval(nextslide, options.slide_interval);

                }else{

                    if ($(pauseplay).attr('src')) $(pauseplay).attr("src", image_path + "play_dull.png");   //If image, swap to play

                    //Mark as paused
                    isPaused = true;

                }

                return false;
            }

        });
    }


    //Pause when hover on image
    if (options.slideshow && options.pause_hover){
        $(element).hover(function() {

            if(inAnimation) return false;       //Abort if currently animating

                if(!(isPaused) && options.navigation){

                    if ($(pauseplay).attr('src')) $(pauseplay).attr("src", image_path + "pause.png");   //If image, swap to pause
                    clearInterval(slideshow_interval);

                }

        }, function() {

            if(!(isPaused) && options.navigation){

                if ($(pauseplay).attr('src')) $(pauseplay).attr("src", image_path + "pause_dull.png");  //If image, swap to active
                slideshow_interval = setInterval(nextslide, options.slide_interval);

            }

        });
    }


    //Adjust image when browser is resized
    $(window).resize(function(){
        resizenow();
    });


    //Adjust image size
    function resizenow() {
        return element.each(function() {

            var t = $('img', element);

            //Resize each image seperately
            $(t).each(function(){
                var ratio = ($(this).height()/$(this).width()).toFixed(2);  //Define image ratio

                //Gather browser size
                var browserwidth = $(window).width();
                var browserheight = $(window).height();
                var offset;

                //Resize image to proper ratio
                if ((browserheight > options.min_height) || (browserwidth > options.min_width)){    //If window larger than minimum height or width

                    if ((browserheight/browserwidth) > ratio){

                        if (options.fit_landscape && ratio <= 1){   //If landscapes are set to fit
                            $(this).width(browserwidth);
                            $(this).height(browserwidth * ratio);
                        }else{                                      //Otherwise handle normally
                            $(this).height(browserheight);
                            $(this).width(browserheight / ratio);
                        }

                    } else {

                        if (options.fit_portrait && ratio > 1){ //If portraits are set to fit
                            $(this).height(browserheight);
                            $(this).width(browserheight / ratio);
                        }else{                                      //Otherwise handle normally
                            $(this).width(browserwidth);
                            $(this).height(browserwidth * ratio);
                        }

                    }   //End dynamic resizing

                }   //End minimum size check

                //Horizontally Center
                if (options.horizontal_center){
                    $(this).css('left', (browserwidth - $(this).width())/2);
                }

                //Vertically Center
                if (options.vertical_center){
                    $(this).css('top', (browserheight - $(this).height())/2);
                }

            });

            //Basic image drag and right click protection
            if (options.image_protect){

                $('img', element).bind("contextmenu",function(){
                    return false;
                });
                $('img', element).bind("mousedown",function(){
                    return false;
                });

            }

            return false;

        });
    };


    //Next slide
    function nextslide() {

        if(inAnimation) return false;       //Abort if currently animating
            else inAnimation = true;        //Otherwise set animation marker

        var slides = options.slides;    //Pull in slides array

        var currentslide = element.find('.activeslide');        //Find active slide
        currentslide.removeClass('activeslide');                //Remove active class

        if ( currentslide.length == 0 ) currentslide = element.find('a:last');  //If end of set, note this is last slide
        var nextslide = currentslide.next().length ? currentslide.next() : element.find('a:first');
        var prevslide = nextslide.prev().length ? nextslide.prev() : element.find('a:last');

        //Update previous slide
        $('.prevslide').removeClass('prevslide');
        prevslide.addClass('prevslide');

        //Get the slide number of new slide
        currentSlide + 1 == slides.length ? currentSlide = 0 : currentSlide++;

        //If hybrid mode is on drop quality for transition
        if (options.performance == 1) element.removeClass('quality').addClass('speed'); 

        /**** Image Loading ****/

        //Load next image
        loadSlide = false;

        currentSlide == slides.length - 1 ? loadSlide = 0 : loadSlide = currentSlide + 1;   //Determine next slide
        imageLink = (options.slides[loadSlide].url) ? "href='" + options.slides[loadSlide].url + "'" : "";  //If link exists, build it
        $("<img/>").attr("src", options.slides[loadSlide].image).appendTo(element).wrap("<a " + imageLink + linkTarget + "></a>");  //Append new image

        //Update thumbnails (if enabled)
        if (options.thumbnail_navigation == 1){

            //Load previous thumbnail
            currentSlide - 1 < 0  ? prevThumb = slides.length - 1 : prevThumb = currentSlide - 1;
            $('#prevthumb').html($("<img/>").attr("src", options.slides[prevThumb].image));

            //Load next thumbnail
            nextThumb = loadSlide;
            $('#nextthumb').html($("<img/>").attr("src", options.slides[nextThumb].image));

        }

        currentslide.prev().remove(); //Remove Old Image

        /**** End Image Loading ****/


        //Update slide number
        if (options.slide_counter){
            $('#slidecounter .slidenumber').html(currentSlide + 1);
        }

        //Update captions
        if (options.slide_captions){
            (options.slides[currentSlide].title) ? $('#slidecaption').html(options.slides[currentSlide].title) : $('#slidecaption').html('');
        }

        nextslide.hide().addClass('activeslide');   //Update active slide

        switch(options.transition){

            case 0:    //No transition
                nextslide.show(); inAnimation = false;
                break;
            case 1:    //Fade
                nextslide.fadeTo(options.transition_speed, 1, function(){ afterAnimation(); });
                break;
            case 2:    //Slide Top
                nextslide.animate({top : -$(window).height()}, 0 ).show().animate({ top:0 }, options.transition_speed, function(){ afterAnimation(); });
                break;
            case 3:    //Slide Right
                nextslide.animate({left : $(window).width()}, 0 ).show().animate({ left:0 }, options.transition_speed, function(){ afterAnimation(); });
                break;
            case 4:    //Slide Bottom
                nextslide.animate({top : $(window).height()}, 0 ).show().animate({ top:0 }, options.transition_speed, function(){ afterAnimation(); });
                break;
            case 5:    //Slide Left
                nextslide.animate({left : -$(window).width()}, 0 ).show().animate({ left:0 }, options.transition_speed, function(){ afterAnimation(); });
                break;
            case 6:    //Carousel Right
                nextslide.animate({left : $(window).width()}, 0 ).show().animate({ left:0 }, options.transition_speed, function(){ afterAnimation(); });
                currentslide.animate({ left: -$(window).width() }, options.transition_speed );
                break;
            case 7:    //Carousel Left
                nextslide.animate({left : -$(window).width()}, 0 ).show().animate({ left:0 }, options.transition_speed, function(){ afterAnimation(); });
                currentslide.animate({ left: $(window).width() }, options.transition_speed );
                break;
        };



    }


    //Previous Slide
    function prevslide() {

        if(inAnimation) return false;       //Abort if currently animating
            else inAnimation = true;        //Otherwise set animation marker

        var slides = options.slides;    //Pull in slides array

        var currentslide = element.find('.activeslide');        //Find active slide
        currentslide.removeClass('activeslide');                //Remove active class

        if ( currentslide.length == 0 ) currentslide = $(element).find('a:first');  //If end of set, note this is first slide
        var nextslide =  currentslide.prev().length ? currentslide.prev() : $(element).find('a:last');
        var prevslide =  nextslide.next().length ? nextslide.next() : $(element).find('a:first');

        //Update previous slide
        $('.prevslide').removeClass('prevslide');
        prevslide.addClass('prevslide');

        //Get current slide number
        currentSlide == 0 ?  currentSlide = slides.length - 1 : currentSlide-- ;

        //If hybrid mode is on drop quality for transition
        if (options.performance == 1) element.removeClass('quality').addClass('speed'); 

        /**** Image Loading ****/

        //Load next image
        loadSlide = false;

        currentSlide - 1 < 0  ? loadSlide = slides.length - 1 : loadSlide = currentSlide - 1;   //Determine next slide
        imageLink = (options.slides[loadSlide].url) ? "href='" + options.slides[loadSlide].url + "'" : "";  //If link exists, build it
        $("<img/>").attr("src", options.slides[loadSlide].image).prependTo(element).wrap("<a " + imageLink + linkTarget + "></a>"); //Append new image

        //Update thumbnails (if enabled)
        if (options.thumbnail_navigation == 1){

            //Load previous thumbnail
            prevThumb = loadSlide;
            $('#prevthumb').html($("<img/>").attr("src", options.slides[prevThumb].image));

            //Load next thumbnail
            currentSlide == slides.length - 1 ? nextThumb = 0 : nextThumb = currentSlide + 1;
            $('#nextthumb').html($("<img/>").attr("src", options.slides[nextThumb].image));
        }

        currentslide.next().remove(); //Remove Old Image

        /**** End Image Loading ****/


        //Update slide counter
        if (options.slide_counter){
            $('#slidecounter .slidenumber').html(currentSlide + 1);
        }

        //Update captions
        if (options.slide_captions){
            (options.slides[currentSlide].title) ? $('#slidecaption').html(options.slides[currentSlide].title) : $('#slidecaption').html('');
        }

        nextslide.hide().addClass('activeslide');   //Update active slide

        switch(options.transition){

            case 0:    //No transition
                nextslide.show(); inAnimation = false;
                break;
            case 1:    //Fade
                nextslide.fadeTo(options.transition_speed, 1, function(){ afterAnimation(); });
                break;
            case 2:    //Slide Top (reverse)
                nextslide.animate({top : $(window).height()}, 0 ).show().animate({ top:0 }, options.transition_speed, function(){ afterAnimation(); });
                break;
            case 3:    //Slide Right (reverse)
                nextslide.animate({left : -$(window).width()}, 0 ).show().animate({ left:0 }, options.transition_speed, function(){ afterAnimation(); });
                break;
            case 4:    //Slide Bottom (reverse)
                nextslide.animate({top : -$(window).height()}, 0 ).show().animate({ top:0 }, options.transition_speed, function(){ afterAnimation(); });
                break;
            case 5:    //Slide Left (reverse)
                nextslide.animate({left : $(window).width()}, 0 ).show().animate({ left:0 }, options.transition_speed, function(){ afterAnimation(); });
                break;
            case 6:    //Carousel Right (reverse)
                nextslide.animate({left : -$(window).width()}, 0 ).show().animate({ left:0 }, options.transition_speed, function(){ afterAnimation(); });
                currentslide.animate({ left: $(window).width() }, options.transition_speed );
                break;
            case 7:    //Carousel Left (reverse)
                nextslide.animate({left : $(window).width()}, 0 ).show().animate({ left:0 }, options.transition_speed, function(){ afterAnimation(); });
                currentslide.animate({ left: -$(window).width() }, options.transition_speed );
                break;  
        };

    }

    //After slide animation
    function afterAnimation() {

        inAnimation = false; 

        //If hybrid mode is on swap back to higher image quality
        if (options.performance == 1){
            element.removeClass('speed').addClass('quality');
        }

        resizenow();

    }

};

})(jQuery);
```

in the HEAD

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/supersized.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/supersized.3.1.1.min.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">  

        jQuery(function($){
            $.supersized({

                //Functionality
                slideshow               :   1,      //Slideshow on/off
                autoplay                :   1,      //Slideshow starts playing automatically
                start_slide             :   1,      //Start slide
                slide_interval          :   3000,   //Length between transitions
                transition              :   1,      //0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                transition_speed        :   500,    //Speed of transition
                new_window              :   1,      //Image links open in new window/tab
                pause_hover             :   0,      //Pause slideshow on hover
                keyboard_nav            :   1,      //Keyboard navigation on/off
                performance             :   1,      //0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)

                //Size & Position
                min_width               :   0,      //Min width allowed (in pixels)
                min_height              :   0,      //Min height allowed (in pixels)
                vertical_center         :   1,      //Vertically center background
                horizontal_center       :   1,      //Horizontally center background
                fit_portrait            :   1,      //Portrait images will not exceed browser height
                fit_landscape           :   0,      //Landscape images will not exceed browser width

                //Components
                navigation              :   1,      //Slideshow controls on/off
                thumbnail_navigation    :   1,      //Thumbnail navigation
                slide_counter           :   1,      //Display slide numbers
                slide_captions          :   1,      //Slide caption (Pull from "title" in slides array)
                slides                  :   [       //Slideshow Images
                                                    {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.1/slides/quietchaos-kitty.jpg', title : 'Quiet Chaos by Kitty Gallannaugh', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2010/12/kitty-gallannaugh/'},
                                                    {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.1/slides/day3-emily.jpg', title : 'Day 3 by Emily Tebbetts', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/02/larissa/'},  
                                                    {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.1/slides/wilderness2.jpg', title : 'Wilderness by Larissa Felsen', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/02/larissa/'} 
                                            ]

            }); 
        });

    </script>
```

Body:

```
<!--Thumbnail Navigation--> 
<div id="prevthumb"></div> <div id="nextthumb"></div> 

<!--Control Bar--> 
<div id="controls-wrapper"> 
    <div id="controls"> 

        <!--Slide counter--> 
        <div id="slidecounter"> 
            <span class="slidenumber"></span>/<span class="totalslides"></span> 
        </div> 

        <!--Slide captions displayed here--> 
        <div id="slidecaption"></div> 

        <!--Navigation--> 
        <div id="navigation"> 
            <img id="prevslide" src="img/back_dull.png"/><img id="pauseplay" src="img/pause_dull.png"/><img id="nextslide" src="img/forward_dull.png"/> 
        </div> 

    </div> 
</div>
```

Hopefully the above helps.

thanks!

Comment: You'll find that few people on this site are willing to assist in "help me with this plugin" type questions. The chances of someone knowing both of these plugins and how they work is quite low. Post some code, you'll get more responses.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, will try to make it easier for those who can help.

Comment: Omar, I have exactly the same problem as you. To modify supersized with a navigation bullet. After whole weeks of research, I still have nothing to find. Any solution?....I absolutely need this modification. Thank you yoann

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are two actions happening. First the total number of slides gets set as does the current position (typically 1).. Then later inside the loop, the current position gets updated. So if you crack open supersized.3.1.3.js see the follwing line numbers: 154, 155, 595, and 690.. The first two line numbers initially place the number values in their home. And the last two update the current slide.

First what you need to do is write the html and css for your dots. Write one div class for dot and and one for dotActive. The dot class is the default state. And when it's active, you will be adding and removing the class dotActive to the elements. Make sure to give them all numeric indexes as it will be way easier when you need to add the dotActive class to the correct element. I'm picturing, dot_1, dot_2, and so on.

Basically you will want to use the value of options.slides.length on line 155 to determine how many elements to create and inject into the html: $('#slidecounter .slidenumber'). Then at the update loops, probably just each() through the .slidenumber collection, doing removeClass - then addClass to the element known by your currentSlide value.. And viola!

Answer (score 0):

A big hint for jQuery: Don't write what's been written!

A popular image slider is [EasySlider](http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.7/02.html).  It can be easily modified to use "bullets" for the navigation like that with a bit of styling.  The link I provided is to a sample which uses numbers.  Might be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks, but I require the whole FULLSCREEN-image slider - Supersized does this already but not the bullet navigation - hence the need to modify it.